# Use same struct on all files from a project

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, struct

I use an instance of a struct in all the files of my project by declaring it within each of the header files.

My question is: is there an easier/automatic method of doing it?

well here is an example:

well, i have a project called: my_project 
that contains: main.c func1.c func2.c func3.c. 
on main file i read txt file and save the data on struct vector:

```
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){ 
  fscanf(f,"%s",&s[i].nome); 
  fscanf(f,"%d",&s[i].id); 
  fscanf(f,"%d",&s[i].quantidade); 
  fscanf(f,"%d",&s[i].lim_min); 
  fscanf(f,"%f",&s[i].consumo_med); 
}
```

and what i want is use the struct vector in func2.c and func3.c

ehst is the best way to do it?

Comment: You'll have to add more details about what you're doing.

Comment: Does my edit say what you wanted to say?

Comment: well, i have a project called: my_project that contains: main.c func1.c func2.c func3.c.
on main file i read txt file and save the data on struct vector:
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){

  fscanf(f,"%s",&s[i].nome);
  fscanf(f,"%d",&s[i].id);
         fscanf(f,"%d",&s[i].quantidade);
  fscanf(f,"%d",&s[i].lim_min);
  fscanf(f,"%f",&s[i].consumo_med);
 
 }
and what i want is use the vector in func2.c and func3.c

Comment: Please edit your question with this code. Very difficult to read in the comments.

Comment: well i hope i made myself clear after editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define struct vector in a header, perhaps called vector.h, and then include vector.h in each of your source files (or in a header that is already included in each of your source files). This is a common way to do it. This has the benefit that the text defining struct vector appears in only one place, vector.h (which avoids errors that occur when the definition is edited in one source file but not another). And it is essentially the only way to do it, since C does not provide any way to import definitions other than #include.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have function declarations in your `funcXYZ.c` files which you're including in `main.c`? You might just code your functions to take an appropriate struct as an argument, then use those functions with the struct you've created in `main`.

If for whatever reason you've got things the other way around, i.e. you're including `main.c` in `funcXYZ.c`, then you might use an [`extern`](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/840).